# Rock paper scissors AI issue

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm building a simple rock paper scissors game. It works fine, except for the fact that the game won't stop when comp_count reaches 3. I can't seem to understand why, since it works fine for player_count. Help me out please!

```
from random import randint

player_count = 0
comp_count = 0

def game():
    player_choice = raw_input('Do you choose rock [r], paper [p], or scissors [s]? ')

    computer_choice = randint(0,2)
    #Rock = 0 Paper = 1 Scissors = 2

    #Player chooses paper, computer chooses rock
    if player_choice == "p" and computer_choice == 0:
        print 'Computer chose rock'
        player_won()

    #Player chooses rock, computer chooses scissors
    elif player_choice == 'r' and computer_choice == 2:
        print 'Computer chose scissors'
        player_won()

    #Player chooses scissors, computer chooses paper
    elif player_choice == 's' and computer_choice == 1:
        print 'Computer chose paper'
        player_won()

    #Computer chooses paper, player chooses rock
    elif player_choice == 'r' and computer_choice == 1:
        print 'Computer chose paper'
        computer_won()

    #Computer chooses rock, player chooses scissors
    elif player_choice == 's' and computer_choice == 0:
        print 'Computer chose rock'
        computer_won()

    #Computer chooses scissors, player chooses paper
    elif player_choice == 'p' and computer_choice == 2:
        print 'Computer chose scissors'
        computer_won()

    #Ties
    elif player_choice == 'r' and computer_choice == 0:
        print "It's a tie!"
        game()

    elif player_choice == 's' and computer_choice == 2:
        print "It's a tie!"
        game()

    elif player_choice == 'p' and computer_choice == 1:
        print "It's a tie!"
        game()

    #Wrong input
    else:
        print 'Please try again.'
        game()

def player_won():
    global player_count
    print 'You win!'
    player_count += 1
    print 'You have ' + str(player_count) + ' point(s).'
    while player_count < 3:
        game()

def computer_won():
    global comp_count
    print 'Computer wins!'
    comp_count += 1
    print 'Computer has ' + str(comp_count) + ' point(s).'
    while comp_count < 3:
        game()

print 'Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors! First to 3 points wins it all.'
game()
```

Comment: It works for `player_count`? Really? I tested your code and it let me win 5 times before I used Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loops are whats causing your problem. Simply change while to a if in your player_won and computer_won functions and it fixes the issue.

```
def player_won():
    global player_count
    print 'You win!'
    player_count += 1
    print 'You have ' + str(player_count) + ' point(s).'
    if player_count < 3:
        game()

def computer_won():
    global comp_count
    print 'Computer wins!'
    comp_count += 1
    print 'Computer has ' + str(comp_count) + ' point(s).'
    if comp_count < 3:
        game()
```

Now go rock paper scissors your heart out!

Answer (score 0):

I admit this isn't really a direct answer to your question, but I feel it might be useful to have a potentially simpler way to write this brought up.

You could make the user choose from three different numbers in the input instead of letters, or just convert the letters to numbers. One advantage of this is that to test for a tie, you could simply write:

```
if player_choice == computer_choice:
```

Even checking for who won in a game if it wasn't a tie wouldn't be very difficult, since if it is all numeric, an option that beats another one will be one away from it in a certain direction. So, for example, you could test if the player won like so:

```
winning = computer_choice - 1
if winning == -1: winning = 2
if player_choice == wining:
    player_won()
else: #assuming we have already checked if it is a tie, we can say that otherwise the computer won.
    computer_won()
```

If each number represented a different option (for example if you had a dictionary linking 0 to rock, 1 to scissors, and 2 to paper), then this would check if the user chose the option before the computer's, which would be the winning option.

That would actually let you check for who won and with which options with relatively few if statements. Your check could look something like this:

```
options = {0: "rock", 1:"scissors", 2:"paper"}

#collect player and computer choice here

print "computer chose "+options[computer_choice] #We will probably tell them what the computer chose no matter what the outcome, so might as well just put it once up here now that a variable can determine what the computer chose.

if player_choice == computer_choice:
    print "It's a tie!"
    game()

winning = computer_choice - 1
if winning == -1: winning = 2

if player_choice == wining:
    player_won()
else: #assuming we have already checked if it is a tie, we can say that otherwise the computer won.
    computer_won()
```

This isn't really necessary for making your code work, but I think it will be useful if you are interested.